# the difference between when, where, and which

Tags: word-choice, relative-pronouns, modifiers

I am confused as to why the "where" in the sentence

> One domain **where** this is of considerable significance is music's potentially damaging effects on the ability to drive safely.

cannot be a "which". Same goes for the sentence

> It had long been something of a mystery where, and  on what, the northern fur seals of the eastern Pacific feed during the winter, **which** they spend off the coast of North America from California to Alaska.

Why can't the "which" in the sentence be a "when"?

Comment: Who told you it couldn't be a "when"?

Comment: In your first sentence, you can't replace *where* with *which*, but you **can** replace it with *in which*.

Answer (score 2):

They <sub>subject</sub> spend <sub>transitive verb</sub> the winter <sub>direct object</sub>   off the coast <sub>locative complement</sub>.

...during **the winter, which** they spend off the coast.

**which** acts as a proxy for **the winter**.  The transitive verb **spends** needs an object; hence, **which**.

The need for an object for transitive verb **spend** is also why **when** cannot be substituted for **which**.

... during **the winter, when** they *spend* off the coast.  <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

These would be grammatical:

... during the winter, when they *spend time* off the coast.

... during the winter, when they *live* <sub>intransitive verb</sub> off the coast.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the reason *why* is because they would have to be *different* sentences

> One domain **where** this is of considerable significance
>   One domain **in which** this is of considerable significance
>
> feed during the winter, **which** they **spend** off the coast of North America
>    feed during the winter, **when** they **are** off the coast of North America

it can not be a straight substitution.